# Forward server process's X11 GUI dynamically to machine of logged in dev

Tags: ssh, x11, x11forwarding

On one of our linux machines we have a server process running. This process mainly uses logs and config files, but a crucial part of the server program uses a specialized GUI, which uses X11.

We need a way to relay this GUI from the linux machine to the machine of any dev/support person which might need the GUI.

I wonder if it is possible to set up the server in such that if you first login with X forwarding (ssh -Y) into another account on the server, and then send a message to the server to show the GUI, that it gets relayed back to the dev machine.

I though that it would be possible to specify an X display number on the linux box for the server process, and then somehow "hook onto it" when logged into the box, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either VNC or NX to connect without destroying the running session.

Comment: The problem is that there might be multiple instances of this GUI for different tasks. Then VNC would be trickier, right? EDIT: What actually happens is that you fill in a sort of TXID in a JMX field and press a button, whereafter you get a UI to view details of the TX. I can automate "pressing button in JMX with ID", but can't control where the GUI pops up.